# How to change Magento product default attribute label

Tags: magento

I have a task here to add extra information in the existing attributes' label as screenshot displays.

[image: Screenshot]

The attributes I am going to modify are `Name`, `Status`, `Visibility`, `Price` and `Special Price`. So first of all, I would like to know if this is doable?

If yes, I would like to know a bit more about how to do it. I tried to search on Google and SO but can't find anything related.

I've done some extensions and some of them are adding custom attributes to product using install script. But I have no idea how to just add extra html to existing attributes' label.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Catalog > Manage Attributes > Select the Attribute , you can edit exisitng Attribute label as below image [image]

Comment: Thanks @vickey-colors, my intention is not only changing the label text, but for example to programmatically get prices from other store views and display in the label. Magento's attribute management wouldn't be able to do that.